# MySQL or MongoDB, which is more costly and by how much?

Tags: mysql, memory, mongodb

I have a dataset of 5 million customers where READ is the most critical operation (avg READ would be 100K rows every half hour). Each customer record contains typical personal information.

What are the approximate hardware requirements/usages when using:

- MySQL
- MongoDB

The main reason I'm not so sure about MongoDB is the high usage of memory. I want to understand if it will make it significantly more costly than MySQL.

Comment: Yep Voting to close with move to dba.

Comment: One database system is not inherently more costly than the other. That comes down to how efficiently you architect your database. The difference between when to choose one over the other is mainly driven by if your schema is ill-defined or changes more frequently than you want to manage in the data layer, and if you care about data integrity or not. As an aside you don't sound like you have a lot of data nor a heavy load of data read requirements. So I wouldn't be concerned regardless.

Comment: @J.D. it sounds like I could have chosen any of them for a new project. So when do you insist on using one or the other when starting a new project?

Comment: @EranBetzalel "*The difference between when to choose one over the other is mainly driven by if your schema is ill-defined or changes more frequently than you want to manage in the data layer, and if you care about data integrity or not.*' 9/10 times a NoSQL database (like MongoDB) is not needed. But some people choose it when it's what they already know and don't have a lot of experience with databases. But if you have a defined structure for your data and / or care about data integrity, you're usually best off just using a traditional RDBMS (like MySQL).